# image not showing in the jsp page after ajax start

Tags: ajax, jsp

My page not showing a gif image while page in ajax request. Its a registration page and while clicking on submit button it should show a spin image and it should disapper after a success

this is my ajax code

```
$("#register-form").on("submit", function() {
        var uname = $('#username').val();
        var phone = $('#phone').val();
        var mail = $('#email').val();
        // $(".loader").show();
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "registerUser",
            secureuri : false,
            cache : false,
            async : false,
            data : {
                "username" : uname,
                "phone" : phone,
                "email" : mail
            },
            success : function(response) {
                $(".status").fadeIn("slow");
                $(".loader").hide();
                $(".status").html(response);

                if (response == "Please check your mail to verify account") {
                    $(".status").css({
                        "border" : "1px solid green",
                        "background-color" : "#B2D47F"
                    });

                }
            },
            error : function() {
                alert("error occured");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

here I am binding ajaxstart

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
        $(".loader").show();
    });
```

but it is not showing.. is anything wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `beforeSend` and `complete` handlers to your ajax call, and show/hide the loader in it. This will also work in case of error, because if you are hiding the loader in `success` handler and error happens, it will stay visible after ajax is completed.

```
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "registerUser",
        secureuri : false,
        cache : false,
        async : false,
        data : {
            "username" : uname,
            "phone" : phone,
            "email" : mail
        },
        beforeSend : function() {
            $(".loader").show();
        },
        success : function(response) {
            ...
        },
        error : function() {
            alert("error occured");
        },
        complete : function() {
            $(".loader").hide();
        },
    });
```

Comment: I tried all these cases before, but I feel like my page get stucked on submit click event and its revert back to the normal stage after success..

Comment: my loading gif image get stucked when ajax start

Comment: @jithinmohan I've edited my answer, are you hiding the loader in `complete` handler? It is executed after `success` or `error`

Comment: yes.. I tried all these.. when I click on submit button, at the very first moment it will get stucked..